# how to use multiple subdomain for multiple cites

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

i am working on a website www(dot)shopingmart(dot)com basically a classified website, i need to solve a problem im facing now i spent to much time but unable to solve. im trying to achieve.

if user visit newyork.example.com or ohio.example.com

both these cities point to same website means www.example.com

but display contents related to city  (like OLX Done)

i have create wildcard domain *.example.com With A record 
i also create two subdomains

```
newyork.example.com and 

ohio.example.com
```

also create .htaccess to redirect traffic to index.php

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

then parse

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] to obtain subdomain
```

but when i type newyork.example.com it will give me 500 Internal error

Please help and share some idea i'm unable to solve this problem

Best Regards

Comment: ugh why the newlines? This is very hard to read.

Comment: MightyPork i edit and update. actually i m new user plz accept apology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a virtual host using a wildcard to accept all subdomains from a specific domain.

This is a config sample of a system I made that do basically what you need:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot /www/your_site
     ServerName example.com
     ServerAlias *.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This makes Apache to receive all subdomains (alias) for a specific domain.

You should first try this approach without your rewrite rules and only insert the rules after wildcard is working.

Edit:

Regarding assets path changing under subdomains, the rewrite rule needs to point to index.php at the document root:

```
RewriteRule . %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]
```

Comment: i already create wildcard subdomain using cpanel. if you visit my website at the top (header section) you see **www** if you enter complete website address(www(dot)shopingmart(dot)com) this show wildcards is working fine. my problem is why its not working when i use newyork.example.com.

Comment: Did you tried to load any static file using these subdomains? If static content is accessible, then your problem might be with your PHP script. If your content is still inaccessible then its some misconfiguration in your virtual host.

Comment: Dear lomantpa Thanks its now working but one thing i need to ask, anything i put before my domain it will change path and site looks like dont have any css. why is this. now do i need to create subdomain for each and every city? any help regarding rewrite rules for cities

Comment: I got a similar issue sometime ago and solved modifying the rewrite rule like this: RewriteRule . %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]. This way you force the path to index.php to be always at the level of your document root. Added this to answer. ;)